# How can i create a New Activity from IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

How can i create a new Activity from IntelliJ for Android PRoject,  and this automatically generates xml File and .Class

[image: This is an image from my IntelliJ]

Comment: welcome to SO, use appropriate tags for your questions

Comment: right-click com.example.mismedicamera. create a new class which extends Activity. add your Activity to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: :( .. in eclipse i can do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Choose the class from the source folder where you want to create the activity.

Right click.

Choose `New` > `Android Component`.

In the `New Android Component Dialogue` choose `Kind` > `Activity`.

Name your Activity and save. You will get a Java source file created that extends `Activity` and `<activity android:name=".view.Sample"/>` line in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the first look, highlight the src folder and click new. currently you have highlighted the layout folder, so it might provide you only those files thats meant to go there.

You can create a java class in src folder which extends the "activity" class.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you can hit control + n (^N) to come up with the same options!